Laravel with Docker: Migration Fails for Second Database with SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out Error
I'm working on a Laravel project where I need to connect to multiple MariaDB databases using Docker. While I can successfully connect to the first database and run migrations, I'm encountering an issue when trying to run migrations on the second database.
Environment Setup:
my env:
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=10.0.0.4
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=x
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

DB_CONNECTION_SECOND=mysql_second
DB_HOST_SECOND=10.0.0.4
DB_PORT_SECOND=3307
DB_DATABASE_SECOND=y
DB_USERNAME_SECOND=root
DB_PASSWORD_SECOND=

database.php:
 'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DB_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'laravel'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => env('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4'),
            'collation' => env('DB_COLLATION', 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'),
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],

        'mysql_second' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST_SECOND', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT_SECOND', '3307'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_SECOND', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME_SECOND', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD_SECOND', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET_SECOND', ''),
            'charset' => env('DB_CHARSET_SECOND', 'utf8mb4'),
            'collation' => env('DB_COLLATION_SECOND', 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'),
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA_SECOND'),
            ]) : [],
        ],

for docker i have two seperate container:
  db:
    image: mariadb:11
    container_name: db
    hostname: mariadb
    volumes:
      - paypipol_db:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: my_root_password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: x
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 
    networks:
      - paypipol

  db2:
    image: mariadb:11
    container_name: db2
    hostname: mariadb2
    volumes:
      - paypipol_db2:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '3307:3306'  # Use a different port for the second database
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: my_root_password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: y
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 
    networks:
      - paypipol

Problem:
When I run the migration for the second database using: docker exec -it backend-dev php artisan migrate --database=mysql_secondI get the following error:
Illuminate\Database\QueryException  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out (Connection: mysql_second, SQL: select table_name asname, (data_length + index_length) as size, table_comment as comment, engine as engine, table_collation as collation from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'y' and table_type in ('BASE TABLE', 'SYSTEM VERSIONED') order by table_name)
Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

Container Status: Both db and db2 containers are up and running without issues. I can connect to each database individually using a MySQL client.
Database Credentials: I double-checked that the credentials in the .env file and database.php configuration match those in the Docker environment variables.
Networking: Both containers are part of the same network, so they should be able to communicate. However, the migration command fails when it tries to connect to the second database (mysql_second).

Additional Information:
The first database (mysql) works fine; I can run migrations and interact with it without any issues.
The error suggests that the connection to the second database (mysql_second) is timing out, but I can't figure out why since the configuration appears to be correct.
What I'm Looking For:
I'm looking for any insights into why the connection to the second database might be timing out. Could it be related to Docker networking, the port configuration, or something else? Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Does db2 have significantly more tables, especially in y? What happens if the SQL statement is directly executed?

Hi, Can you add your migration files ? Did you try to specify Schema::connection('mysql_second') ?

fixed by replacing DB_HOST_SECOND=10.0.0.4
with DB_HOST_SECOND=mariadb2
